# Выравнивание меню на CSS и на JS. 2 Вопроса

Tags: javascript, css

```css
* {
  vertical-align: table;
}
.class_a1 {
  border: 1px solid #00ffff;
}
.class_l1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
.class_r1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
.class_f0 {
  clear: both;
}
.class_l1_p0 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
это ужасный DIV
<br>
<div class="class_a1">

  <div class="class_l1">
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
    <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="class_r1">RIGHT</div>
  <div class="class_f0"></div>

</div>

<br>
<br>это нормальная TABLE
<br>

<table class="class_a1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="class_l1">
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point1</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point2</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point3</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point4</div>
        <div class="class_l1_p0">Point5</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="class_r1">RIGHT</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вопрос 1: Как сделать на CSS, что бы div'ы не сдвигали друг друга на другую строку

Вопрос 2: Как сделать на JS, что бы не влезшие в строку пункты меню помещались в выпадающий список? Допустим я у браузера окно сделал уже, ширина изменилась

То, что спрашиваю - видел, но в моем гугле отсутствует.

Comment: Попробуйте написать задания простым человеческим языком, как в итоге это дело должно работать. В данной интерпретации, ваши вопросы создают больше ответных вопросов, чем ответов. Пример простого вопроса: "Хочу сделать меню, в котором все пункты будут зелёные, а при нажатии на эти пункты они становились красные, а если нажать ещё раз - жёлтые". То есть, подробно объяснить все события в вашем видении, которые должны происходить, а не "изменить стиль div class_l1, что бы при неизвестной ширине class_r1, не переносила этот блок"

Comment: поправил. да, не очень понятно спросил

Comment: @media вам в помощь - попробуйте использовать mediaqueris